# approximation a sawtooth like function in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

i'm trying to approximate a function shown in the image below. the exponential part of the function is not needed by all means, so its basically just a saw tooth ranging from -pi to pi, with the width getting samller from period to period. but i just can't approximate it. another important thing,is the function starting at -pi. i would appreciate it if someone could give me any hints how to approximate a function like this.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by approximate? do you want an equation for that or you have data and you want to fit data on a model?

Comment: hey, yes i'm looking for an equation

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint to start. 
The general equation for an exponentially damped sinusoid may be represented as:

[image]

where, **y** is the instantaneous amplitude at time **t**

**A** is the initial amplitude of the envelope.

**lambda** is the decay constant, in the reciprocal of the time units of the X axis.

**phi** is the phase angle at some arbitrary point.

**omega** is the Angular frequency.

and it can be simplified to the following equation:

[image]

You need to replace the **saw** function instead of the **cosine** function.